# hook_init called a second time on ajax

Tags: 7, hooks

I am using hook_init to check if a variable is set, and then redirect if not...

```
function quickstart_init() {
  if (variable_get('quickstart_admin', 0) != 1 && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/welcome/admin') {
    drupal_goto('welcome/admin');
  }
}
```

This works for logged out users, but when you are logged in, it redirects - but the whole page displays twice!

I have traced this down to admin menu, as the second version of the page only appears once that JS runs. Does anyone know if admin_menu bootstraps onload? In which case, probably run hook_init again?

Anyway, main question....

What can i do to only run this once, is there something other than hook init that would work?

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to get to the bottom of why hook_init is being called twice, but for a band-aid solution, you can use a static variable (using drupal_static) to keep track of whether your implementation of hook_init has already been called.